# Getting fitted outouts from hideen layer in CNN

Tags: neural-network, keras, convolutional-neural-network

I have a fitted CNN model through keras, with a convolution layer and pooling layer before 2 hidden layers.  What I would like to see is the training data which is transformed through the final hidden layer, before the output layer.  In other words, after the fitting is done, I'd like to examine the training data after it goes through the fitted convolution and pooling layers, as well as the hidden layers.  Is there a good way to get to that data?